# Get WordPress Child Page IDs

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to shorten this code and instead of manually placing all children Id's, I'd like to pull out only the id's and set it to array. this could be something dynamic in the future when they are adding new child page from the parent page.

```
if ( in_array($post->ID, ['39','41','43','45']) ) {
  $menuPage = 'about';
} elseif ( in_array($post->ID, ['47','49','51','53','55','57']) ) {
  $menuPage = 'asset';
}

get_template_part( _menu, $menuPage );
```

I tried some codes but it technically display the title only. Where I am currently using similar to this code.

```
<ul class="uk-nav uk-navbar-dropdown-nav uk-list uk-list-inline">
  <?php
  $args = array(
      'depth' => 1,
      'include' => 15,
      'title_li' => '',
  );
  wp_list_pages($args);
  $args['child_of'] = $args['include'];
  unset($args['include']);
  wp_list_pages($args);
  ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify the menu to be printed by using `wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_ID );`, see codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_parent_id

Will check the parent ID of every visited child page, then use PHP switch to match the menu.

```
switch(wp_get_post_parent_id( $post->ID )){
   case 1: //parent page ID
     $menuPage = 'about'; 
     break;
   case 2: //parent page ID
     $menuPage = 'asset'; 
     break;
   default:
     $menuPage = 'default-menu';
}
```

Also, if you only want to return the child pages from a specific parent, you can use:

```
$args = array(
    'child_of' => $post->ID,
); 
$pages = get_pages($args);
```

Comment: i never thought of `wp_get_post_parent_id` is the correct way to do this. interesting. thanks much for your help! indeed, your answer solve my case!